# "Error MSB8020: The build tools for WindowsUserModeDriver10.0 cannot be found." But

Tags: tfs, msbuild, wdk, umdf

The first build of a `UMDF` driver solution each day yields the error:

> "Error MSB8020: The build tools for WindowsUserModeDriver10.0 (Platform Toolset = 'WindowsUserModeDriver10.0') cannot be found."

However, if I log into the build server and start up `VS 2017` and shut it down again, then the build will work for the rest of the day - even if I log the build user out of the build server.  I need the build to work irrespective of whether `VS 2017` has been started up on the build server that day.

This has me stumped. I've googled far and wide but maybe I don't know what to search or I'm not recognizing the answer when I see it. I don't know what VS is doing that makes WindowsUserModeDriver10.0 work for the `TFS` Build.

I was going to show a screenshot of the build task definition but that doesn't seem to be an option. But even so, the only thing there that I can see that might be helpful is if there is an argument to provide to `Visual Studio Build` task.

The build should always work irrespective of whether Visual Studio started up on the build server that day or not.

Addendum: This morning I left `VS 2017` running on the build server.  The build has failed again and this time all I had to do was login to the build server.  My session was still active because `VS 2017` was still running. So now I'm really puzzled.

More: This morning, I'm having no trouble building and have not logged into the build server so it is not simply because I have or have not started `VS 2017` on the build server.  Rather, it seems to be intermittent. To try to mitigate the problem for now, I added a cloned task of the build task that will only run if a previous step fails, in order to give it a second chance to succeed.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? We're running into a similar problem

Comment: Same here, any update on this issue?

Comment: Sorry, this was long enough ago that I barely remember the project.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else facing this issue `>=2022`:

This is most certainly an issue with the WDK version being incompatible with your Visual Studio version.

From the table at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/other-wdk-downloads#step-1-install-visual-studio, check that your targeted platform matches your Visual Studio version and the WDK version. After installing the WDK, it should prompt you to also install a Visual Studio extension, which is required:

> Starting with Windows 10, version 1709, installing the WDK will by default install the WDK extensions for Visual Studio. These extensions are required for integration of the WDK with Visual Studio.

For example: If you want to install [WDK for Windows 10, version 2004](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/other-wdk-downloads#step-2-install-the-wdk), that is only supported by Visual Studio 2019 (see [table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/other-wdk-downloads#step-1-install-visual-studio)).

**TIPP:** If you're using Visual Studio 2022, you need to install WDK for Windows 11. That should be no problem. Just make sure to also install the Windows 11 SDK (version `10.0.22621.0`).

Comment: > you need to install WDK for Windows 11.
It isn't clear if the WDK for Windows 11 will satisfy the error message `The build tools for WindowsUserModeDriver10.0 (Platform Toolset = 'WindowsUserModeDriver10.0`, which it seems like it won't.